# Unexpected end of json input ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

As i was using ionic3 and i cant understand where is problem and it show " Unexpected end of JSON input" when i try to make login function and at the response side the data also is blank.

Or will it be an API connection problem？？？

I unable to solve it ,anyone know please teach me i will appreciate~

login.ts

```
login(){
  this.authService.postData(this.userData,'login').then((result) => {
   this.responseData = result;
   if(this.responseData.userData){
   console.log(this.responseData);
   localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.responseData)|| "[]");
   this.navCtrl.push(IframePage);
   }
   else{ swal({
    title: "Invalid Username or Password",
    text: "Please Try Again",
    icon: "warning",

  }); }
 }, (err) => {
   // Error log
 });
```

auth-service.ts

```
  this.http.post(apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify(credentials),{headers:headers})
    .subscribe(res => {
      resolve(res.json());
    }, (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: paste full code of auth-service.ts

Comment: import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

let apiUrl = 'http://www.wiptrainee.com/taxsentral/api/';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(public http : Http) { }
  postData(credentials, type) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let headers = new Headers();
      this.http.post(apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers})
        .subscribe(res => {
          resolve(res.json());
        }, (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });}}

Comment: no need of promise just return the http and subscribe to it

Comment: which angular version is this?. Also try `console.log(res)` before`res.json()`

Comment: can u show me? because i dont understand what means or it just delete word promise?

Comment: In angular http will return an instance of rxjs observable so you no need of promise in that case. Just return the http request and subscribe to it. And one main thing we are using rxjs map operator to transform in to json in http request so you need to import the map operator from rxjs

Comment: @AbineshJoyel but why how the json doesn't work??

Comment: @StevenNg I am not getting you. can you elaborate

Comment: @AbineshJoyel It means after "unexpected error of JSON " problem is solved .I continue use that login function to insert data and data will not auto convert into json.type through my api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

auth.service.ts

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

     return this.http.post(apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify(credentials),{headers:headers}).map(res => res.json())
```

Do subscribe in login function

```
login(){
  this.authService.postData(this.userData,'login').subscribe((result) => {
   this.responseData = result;
   if(this.responseData.userData){
   console.log(this.responseData);
   localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.responseData)|| "[]");
   this.navCtrl.push(IframePage);
   }
   else{ swal({
    title: "Invalid Username or Password",
    text: "Please Try Again",
    icon: "warning",

  }); }
 }, (err) => {
   // Error log
 });
```